# Compare two DataFrames based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a single DataFrame that I duplicated to create two DataFrames. I am trying to compare the two DataFrames to see if the following conditions are being met:

1. IDs from df1 are in df2
2. There is a KeyDate in df2 that is greater than df1

*Note: KeyDate is created based on three columns 'IDs', 'Year', and 'Quater'. And the overall question I am answering is if the ID is repeated at a later date.*

df1

| IDs | Year | Quater | KeyDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 2020 | 1 | 00000120201 |
| 000111 | 2020 | 1 | 00011120201 |
| 000121 | 2020 | 1 | 00012120201 |
| 002011 | 2020 | 1 | 00201120201 |
| 000111 | 2021 | 1 | 00011120211 |
| 000121 | 2022 | 2 | 00012120222 |
| 000121 | 2022 | 3 | 00012120223 |

df2

| IDs | Year | Quater | KeyDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 2020 | 1 | 00000120201 |
| 000111 | 2020 | 1 | 00011120201 |
| 000121 | 2020 | 1 | 00012120201 |
| 002011 | 2020 | 1 | 00201120201 |
| 000111 | 2021 | 1 | 00011120211 |
| 000121 | 2022 | 2 | 00012120222 |
| 000121 | 2022 | 3 | 00012120223 |

Output

| IDs | Year | Quater | Results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000001 | 2020 | 1 | No |
| 000111 | 2020 | 1 | Yes |
| 000121 | 2020 | 1 | Yes |
| 002011 | 2020 | 1 | No |
| 000111 | 2021 | 1 | No |
| 000121 | 2022 | 2 | Yes |
| 000121 | 2022 | 3 | No |

The actual data is well over 1 million lines, which makes iterations/for loops slow. I have also tried the following:

```
df3['Results'] = len(df['IDs']==df2['IDs'] & df1['KeyDate']<df2['KeyDate'])
```

```
df3 = pd.Series(np.where(len(df['IDs']==df2['IDs'] & df1['KeyDate']<df2['KeyDate'])>0,'Yes','No'),
         name='Results').astype(str)
```

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1['IDs'].astype(int),
                df1['Year'].astype(int),
                df1['Quaters'].astype(int),
                pd.Series(np.where(df1['IDs']==df2['IDs'],
                                   (np.where(df1['KeyDate']<df2['KeyDate'],'Yes','No')),'No'), name='Results').astype(str)], axis=1)
```

If this can be completed using one DataFrame that is great and fine. I do not need to duplicate, nor do I need the 'KeyDate'. Both of these I made during my attempts and failures.